# Getting a "General error mounting filesystems" after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: installation, boot

When I turn on his computer, the GNU GRUB menu appears. When I choose the Ubuntu option,[this shows up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2blD6.jpg) What do I do?

```
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system.
root@Sai-Medical:~#
```

Comment: Does it appear straight after the GRUB menu? Do you have btrfs file system? Have you tried selecting rescue mode in GRUB?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu!  It generally helps if you give a more descriptive title to your question.  In this case it found that the exact same question has been asked before - check the other one for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Boot-Repair Tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Many cases of problems relating to the boot are a mal-function or bad-installation of Grub or something related to the MBR and partition table, noticing that Boot Repair Tool was created aiming to give an easy way to fix this common problem, recommended by Ubuntu team.

**Obs.:** If you don't get access to the internet during use of Boot-Repair you won't get the URL mentioned below that can give us important details about your problem in case the recommended repair doesn't work.

### Get a CD including Boot-Repair

Since you are unable to start Ubuntu there are two options to get Boot Repair Tool:

1. Use [this ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) to create a bootable Live-CD/USB of Boot-Repair Tool
2. Boot your pc from [Linux Security Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxSecureRemix) where Boot-Repair Tool will be included by default

Choose one of the options, start Boot-Repair and click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to us as it will give us more information about the error.

For more details and info about advanced options please read [this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).